# Higher order function in F#

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming

Hi everyone I want to express the function call to test1 without firstly defining the function higher

```
let higher = fun a b -> a>b
let rec test1 test2 number list=

        match (number,list) with
        |number,[]                           -> []
        |number,x1::xs when test2 a x = true -> x1::test1 test2 number xs 
        |number,x1::xs                       -> test1 test2 number xs 

printfn "%A" (test1 (higher 5 [5;2;7;8]))
```

Comment: `if a > b then true else false` can be written more concisely as `a > b`.

Comment: Yes, that is how local bindings work. They are local, not global.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. Values and functions that are defined within a function are only accessible within that function, they are not visible from the outside.

This allows us to define helper functions and intermediate values without polluting the global namespace.

For the function `higher` to be accessible outside of function `test1`, you need to define it either before or after `test1`, but not inside it. Anything defined inside `test1` will only be accessible inside `test1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to define `higher` but pass on a function to `test1` that does the same, just pass a function literal:

```
printfn "%A" (test1 ((fun a b -> a > b) 5 [5;2;7;8]))
```

or, since in this case you are just straight comparing two operands, even shorter:

```
printfn "%A" (test1 ((>) 5 [5;2;7;8]))
```